# Usage of Exception base class in C++ is causing the app to crash

Tags: c++, visual-c++, exception, throw

IN the below code snippet why is that if I include the catch statement with "exception base class I get a app crash" (attached the image of teh crash).

But if I use

> "const char* msg"

in catch() it works fine.

**WHy is it that the exception base class is causing teh app crash ?**

```
double division(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
    {
        throw "Division by zero condition!";
    }
    return (a / b);
}
main()
{
    int x = 50;
        int y = 0;
        double z = 0;

        try {
            z = division(x, y);
            cout << "after division func" << endl;
            cout << z << endl;
        }
        catch (const char* msg) {  // WORKS FINE
        //catch (exception& err) {  // CAUSES the APP to crash![enter image description here][1]

            cout << "INside catch for divide by 0" << endl;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Your exception isn't being caught, not all exceptions derive from `std::exception`.

Comment: Well, this `throw "Division by zero condition!";` isn't throwing an `std::exception`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are throwing a string literal:

```
throw "Division by zero condition!";
```

Which can be caught with the following:

```
catch (const char* msg)
```

However this exception does not derive from the class `std::exception`. If you want one which is and can provide an error message then use [`std::runtime_error`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/runtime_error/).

```
throw std::runtime_error("Division by zero condition!");
...
catch (std::exception& err)
```

Comment: BUt since std::exception is the base class, will it not catch strings like 
"throw("abcd");" ?

Comment: @codeLover It is not the base class of all exceptions, there is no such base class in C++. It is just a utility class provided by the standard library for a suggested exception hierarchy. In real world usage nearly everybody uses `std::exception` as the base for all their exception classes and things like throwing string literals and catching everything with `catch(...)` are held to be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

**Division by zero condition is not derived by std::exception**

one workaround you can do is to define catch all statement in you code

```
try {
            z = division(x, y);
            cout << "after division func" << endl;
            cout << z << endl;
    }

        catch (exception& err) {  // CAUSES the APP to crash![enter image description here][1]

            cout << "INside catch for divide by 0" << endl;
        }

        catch(...)    //include this in your code
        {
            cout<<"other exception occured";
        }
```

See here http://ideone.com/TLukAp